# Techniques for measuring the ripple current of SMD electrolytic capacitors

Tags: current-measurement, ac-dc, electrolytic-capacitor, ripple-current

I am currently creating a test plan for an AC/DC converter (90VAC...264VAC -> 12VDC) I've been working on. Since the output electrolytic capacitors are of SMD type, I am trying to come up with possible solutions for reliably and safely measuring the ripple current through them, in order to estimate the lifetime of the power supply.
Preferably, it would have to be scalable because the measurement will be carried out inside of a temperature chamber as well.

Any ideas how it could be accomplished?

Comment: If you can, try a small pulsed current source and read the voltage drop on the discontinuities, due to resistance (oscilloscope needed).

Comment: If one end is at ground, sample the AC and DC voltages across the cap. ESR will rise with age, leading to a higher AC component and higher losses. If you have VAC(RMS) and ESR, can work out current.